# Airflow Dag using python operator to copy files from one to other folder in local system

Tags: python, airflow

```
import os

import shutil
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def copy_tdsx_hyper_template_if_not_exists(source_files, destination_folder):
    for source_file in source_files:
        file_name = os.path.basename(source_file)
        destination_path = os.path.join(destination_folder, file_name)
        if not os.path.exists(destination_path):
            shutil.copyfile(source_file, destination_path)
            print(f"Template File '{file_name}' copied successfully.")
```

## Define the DAG

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'test',
    'retries': 5,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=2)
}

with DAG(
    default_args=default_args,
    dag_id="HyperAPI_extracts_dag_test",
    description="DAG Operation Using Python Operator",
    start_date=datetime(2023, 5, 28),
    schedule='@daily'
) as dag:
    # Define the task
    parent_dir = 'C:\localfolder\'

Tableau_extract_name = 'TestExtract'

my_source_files = [
    parent_dir + 'Tdsx_Hyper_Templates\\' + Tableau_extract_name + '.hyper',
    parent_dir + 'Tdsx_Hyper_Templates\\' + Tableau_extract_name + '.tdsx'
]
my_destination_folder = parent_dir

copy_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='copy_tdsx_hyper_temp_task',
    python_callable=copy_tdsx_hyper_template_if_not_exists,
    op_args=[my_source_files, my_destination_folder],
    dag=dag,
)

# Set task dependencies
copy_task
```

I am getting error like below in Airflow
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Comment: How to  run airflow? Via docker or locally?

Comment: Via Docker only

Comment: you need to mount this volume in the docker-compose. the docker is not familiar with C drive

Comment: @ozs can u pls elaborate this i just want copy file from one folder to another in my local system using Airflow dag

Answer (score 0):

You are escaping a quotation mark:

> `parent_dir = 'C:\localfolder\'`

Please correct with:

```py
parent_dir = 'C:\\localfolder\\'
```

Is that just a typo or is it in the real code too?

Answer (score 0):

Your airflow docker is not familiar with the host, and you need to mount a volume in the docker-compose for that.

Under section "x-common/volumes" map your volume (see below), and then in the DAG use the mapping "/localfolder" for your parent_dir

also use / instead of \\

```
 x-common:
  &common
  image: apache/airflow:2.3.0
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID}:0"
  env_file: 
    - .env
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    - "C:/localfolder:/localfolder"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ozs i tried but no luck added  - 
       /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    - "C:/workSpace/HyperAPI_Extract_wise/data/" in the yamael file

Comment: added same in  parent_dir = "C:/workSpace/HyperAPI_Extract_wise/data/"

Comment: what it the name of the volume you created (right side) ? in the example its parent_dir=/localfolder . you can not use windows path in the dag, airflow docker based on linux. (also the docker.sock not related , I copied it from airflow docker file)

Comment: update like this - "C:/workSpace/HyperAPI_Extract_wise/data/:/localfolder" and parent_dir = "/localfolder" but this is also throwing same error No such file or directory

Comment: @Sreenu131, it might be permissions issue. the docker is running with AIRFLOW_UID user and this folder might not have permssions. try enter the docker with docker exec -it --rm {your_container_name} /bin/bash and check if you see /localhost and can access the files